# Install TestFlight itself on device

Tags: ios, testflight

When a user adds their first device to TestFlight and creates their account, it installs an app that's a wrapper for the mobile version of the **TestFlight** site.  This provides a convenient way for them to install any builds the developer sends them without having to go through their e-mail.

When they go through the process again on another device, it doesn't install the app - only the TestFlight over-the-air provisioning profile.

How can they get that app on their second device, or if they inadvertently delete it from the first one?  They can add a Mobile Safari shortcut for the page to their home screen, but that's not quite the same as it then opens the page in mobile Safari.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following [these instructions from TestFlight.](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829655-why-is-the-testflight-icon-on-my-device-white-)

Comment: This is an excellent link - but interestingly, the device has no profiles listed under General > Profiles (!!!), so I can't follow those instructions.  It seems like a bug of some kind, though - I'll ping the TestFlight crew and see what they say.

Comment: If it does not have any profiles installed then try to continue with the other steps. Did you check if TestFlight WebClip was installed? You may need to delete that one as well.

Comment: Turns out it's a bug they're working on - there's currently no way to get the TestFlight WebClip on an iOS 6.0.1.  Your answer should work for devices that don't have this problem.

Comment: I guess a shortcut will do for now.

Comment: The link directs to a page showing: "This article doesn't have a translation for English". When answering questions with a link: please add a bit more information in order to make the answer useless upon link rot.

Answer (score 2):

*Since the link in the accepted answer is no longer valid, I give you an additional answer
with the instructions shamelessy stolen from the (at the moment) [correct link.](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829655-why-is-the-testflight-icon-on-my-device-white-)
(Hopefully this answer will prove useful even if the link rots.)*

**Sometimes Mobile Safari causes web clip issues and they need to be re-created. Here's how to do that:**

1. Delete the TestFlight webclip from your device.
2. Remove the TestFlight WebClip profile. (Settings > General > Profile)
3. Clear History, Cookies and Data for Safari.
4. Restart your device.
5. Login to https://testflightapp.com/m/login on Mobile Safari.
6. Tap Connect Device.
7. Tap Install on the Install Profile page and follow the prompts to install the profile and web clip.
8. Tap Done once you see profile installed.